# Operations that Preserve Convexity

Tags: convex-optimization, convex

If g, f, and q are convex functions, here are three derived functions, which of below would be convex?

- h(x,y)=(f(x)+g(y))^2
- sqrt(f(x)g(y))
- q(f(x))

How to show that they preserves convexity?

I know the basic operations that preserves convexity, but how about those function compositions?

Answer (score 0):

One great resource for this would be Disciplined Convex Programming (DCP).
CVX for MATLAB has a great documentation on the [DCP Ruleset](http://web.cvxr.com/cvx/doc/dcp.html#dcp).

Given some pre defined atoms it gives a guideline about composition of those atoms to create a convex problem.